# Show new line instead of \n

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am experimenting with HTML5's new [LocalStorage](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2011/01/12/asp-net-and-html5-local-storage) and so far I have been successfully in capturing the content (text) inputted onto my form and storing it in the LocalStorage.

My problem starts when a person comes back to the page, I want the LocalStorage values loaded into the correct input on my form.

I am also doing this with success, however my users would see the following:

[image: textarea with text]

But I would like them to see the text without the double quotes and new lines characters, so I would like them to see:

> Hi
>
> How are you

Just like what they inputted originally. How can I achieve this?

To set the value of the text area, I am using the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    allTextAreasOnPage.each(function(index, entry) {
        var idOfTextArea = $(this).attr('id');
        if (pageLocalStorage.get(idOfTextArea)) {
            $(this).val(pageLocalStorage.get(idOfTextArea));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How are you setting the value of the `textarea`? My first guess is that you're encoding your string _twice_ (because of the quotes)

Comment: That looks fine. How are you filling the local storage?

Comment: Same as the link I provided (first line).

Comment: Are you sure the `JSON.parse` is still in the `get` function? Either you're encoding twice, and decoding once / or encoding once and never decoding.

Comment: Ah no I removed the JSON.parse bit from the get, because it was giving me some error at the time. let me add it back and see what happens.

Comment: take out the json on the save and load, you don't need to waste bytes packing up strings: localStrorage handles strings already...

Comment: @dandavis maybe he wants to store other kinds of values too.

Comment: not in the same localStroarage slot he doesn't- look at the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like your string is being stored as JSON...

```
$(this).val(JSON.parse(pageLocalStorage.get(idOfTextArea)));
```

Should solve it, but you should look into the cause...

Answer (score 1):

When you link code, make sure you're actually using the code you *say* you're using.

..

Comment: There is no answer because OP made a mistake.

Comment: fair enough, but is such an answer worth the risk?

Comment: My apologies. Like I said, I did originally use the `JSON.get()` but removed it due to an error in the console. I should have clarified that in the original Q.